# Calling JavaScript function from an external file in asp.net - error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a JavaScript function in a separate file with a name like home.js /
now I want to call it / 
with asp button / 
and OnClientClick event / 
but the following error occurs: 
Parser Error Message: The 'OnClientClick' property cannot be set declaratively. / 
I do not know where is the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Please show us some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the 'onclientclick' property in the code behind, e.g.

```
btnSave.OnClientClick = "MyJSFunction();";
```

You can't set it in the markup (declaratively).